# if statement with two column output

Tags: bash, scripting

I do have an output as shown below. My plan is to get the first column and do a if statement greater than n value it will get the IP second column and drop the connection.

```
cat file| egrep "invalid|password" | egrep -v "Accepted|preauth" | awk '{print $13}' |sort | uniq -c

   6 61.177.172.35
4083 61.177.172.22
   3 69.28.94.192
  10 80.2.33.180
```

I can extract the first column and do the if statement but don't know how can attribute the value with a corresponding IP.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `if` statement part ? Just print depending on `n` value ? If that's so, I think what you want can be done in just one awk line instead of several pipes

Comment: *"Can someone guide me on what is the best approach?"*  Please **look into `iptables`** as you're reinventing the wheel.  With iptables you can set up maximum connections per IP address quite easily; for a starting point, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139285/135943

Comment: @Wildcard thanks but I am not using iptables instead its firewall-cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

value=1 # to be defined

egrep "invalid|password" file |
egrep -v "Accepted|preauth" |
awk '{print $13}' |
sort |
uniq -c | 
while read -r num ip; do
    if ((num > value)); then
        doSomethingWith "$ip"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is it bash? `If (`? `$num`?

Comment: Yes it's bash code (arithmetic)

Comment: If it is `bash` I would expect `((num>value))` or `[ $num -ge $value ]`, also `if` without `then`? C-style brackets?

Comment: Oops, good catch !

Comment: Below is the script I did. I can get the desired value for $brute but I need its corresponding value in badip.                                                                                         >#!/bin/bash
brute=$(cat /var/log/secure | egrep "invalid|password" | awk '{print $13}' |sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}')
badip=$(cat /var/log/secure | egrep "invalid|password" | awk '{print $13}' |sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}')
for i in $brute; do
#### Check all the line of the output of variable $brute
if [ $i -gt 10 ];
then
  echo $i
fi
done

Comment: Never paste a script in a comment. I recommend to use `fail2ban`, don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page