# How to limit 1 connect per 5 seconds? (IPTABLES)

Tags: firewall

I want to limit 1 connect per 5 seconds using IPTABLES for people, which are connecting to port "12871/12881". I was trying to find rule for it, but ineffectively.

Comment: I would not do that, as it would cause a connection failure to last much longer than it should. It might even last a full 5 seconds, from time to time if connection rates are higher.

Comment: I lead server in game, which have broken Easy Anty Cheat and if there are many connects in one time it break whole server and no one can connect
So the solution for it is limit connections in one time to 1 on 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 12871:12881 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This will reject connections above 15 from one source IP.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 150/second --limit-burst 160 -j ACCEPT
```

In this 160 new connections (packets really) are allowed before the limit of 150 NEW connections (packets) per second is applied.

```
iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 12871:12881 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j REJECT
```

This limits to 3 connections per IP.

Got the info from: [Limit max connections per IP address and new connections per second with iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable)

Example: Limit Connections Per Second

The following example will drop incoming connections if IP make more than 3 connection attempts to port 12871:12881 within 5 seconds.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 3 -j DROP
```

Just change eth0 to your interface id...

The hitcount and seconds can be taylored to your needs.

Comment: It wont be enough. I need to do something like a "queue" of connects - for example 1 connect per 5 seconds.

Comment: Made ajustments to my answer. @onStyle