# How to limit 1 connection per 5 seconds? (IPTABLES)

Tags: iptables, firewall

I want to limit 1 connect per 5 seconds using IPTABLES for people, which are connecting to port "12871/12881". I was trying to find rule for it, but ineffectively.
It must be like a "queue" of connects - for example 1 connect per 5 seconds.

I had here discussion: 
[How to limit 1 connect per 5 seconds? (IPTABLES)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483721/how-to-limit-1-connect-per-5-seconds-iptables) but Im not able to reply on this account, previous was unregistered and logged me out.

Answer (score 2):

Example: Limit Connections Per Second

The following example will drop incoming connections if IP make more than 3 connection attempts to port 12871:12881 within 5 seconds.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 3 -j DROP
```

Just change eth0 to your interface id...

The hitcount and seconds can be tailored to your needs.

I don't know, but it seems like your hardware is just not up to running a HurtWorld server.

Try running it with these options:

```
  - batchmode
  - nographics
  - exec "host 12871;queryport 12881"
  - servername whateveryouwant
  - addadmin "<My Steam ID>" 
  - logfile "gamelog.txt"
```

Ref:

https://hurtworld.gamepedia.com/Hosting_A_Server

https://linuxgsm.com/lgsm/hwserver/

https://docs.linuxgsm.com/configuration/linuxgsm-config

Comment: @Michale Prokopec If there will be at specific time more than 3 connects all the time no one will connect - they will try to connect until they won't do it.

Comment: After 3 connection attempts in 5 seconds by the same IP that IP is ignored. You can change it so after 2 connection attempts within 2 seconds that IP is ignored.

Comment: "wll drop incoming connections if IP make more than 3 connection". Server have 100 slots for players. In one time connects 100+ different IPs, so these connections are not making one user, but 100 different users. I must do something like: 1 player -> 5 seconds -> 2 player -> 5 seconds

Comment: If the above will not work, the're are resource or other config issues if you're still having issues.

Comment: Yeah it don't work. If one connect, it must stop other connects for 5 seconds.

Comment: fyi. if you are adding these rules to another machine in front of your server. You should add it to FORWARD chain instead of INPUT.